# Gaussian random numbers with swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to update an old objective-c project to swift. I need to generate gaussian random numbers. In objective-c I used this:

```
double gaussrand()
{
    static double V1, V2, S;
    static int phase = 0;
    double X;

    if(phase == 0) {
        do {
            double U1 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            double U2 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

            V1 = 2 * U1 - 1;
            V2 = 2 * U2 - 1;
            S = V1 * V1 + V2 * V2;
        } while(S >= 1 || S == 0);

        X = V1 * sqrt(-2 * log(S) / S);
    } else
        X = V2 * sqrt(-2 * log(S) / S);

    phase = 1 - phase;

    return X;
}
```

However this doesn't translate well into swift. Anybody know a way to generate gaussian random numbers given a mean and a standard deviation in sfift 2.1?

Comment: What exactly doesn't translate well? Do you have problems with the `static` variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that as you have defined it, you want `gaussRand` to be a computed property. Computed properties in Swift cannot store other properties, so in the example of a Swift version of your Box-Muller transformation method implementation, I've wrapped the computed property `gaussRand` in a class, and kept `s`, `v2` and `cachedNumberExists` as stored properties in this same class, allowing for every 2nd call `gaussRand` to return the cached result from previous one.

```
class MyRandomGenerator {
    // stored properties
    var s : Double = 0.0
    var v2 : Double = 0.0
    var cachedNumberExists = false

    // (read-only) computed properties
    var gaussRand : Double  {
        var u1, u2, v1, x : Double
        if !cachedNumberExists {
            repeat {
                u1 = Double(arc4random()) / Double(UINT32_MAX)
                u2 = Double(arc4random()) / Double(UINT32_MAX)
                v1 = 2 * u1 - 1;
                v2 = 2 * u2 - 1;
                s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
            } while (s >= 1 || s == 0)
            x = v1 * sqrt(-2 * log(s) / s);
        }
        else {
            x = v2 * sqrt(-2 * log(s) / s);
        }
        cachedNumberExists = !cachedNumberExists
        return x
    }
}
```

We assert that we get the expected results:

```
// Assert expected results
var myRandomGenerator = MyRandomGenerator()

let numGaussNumbers = 1000
var myGaussArr = [Double](count: numGaussNumbers, repeatedValue: 0.0)
for (i,_) in myGaussArr.enumerate() { myGaussArr[i] = myRandomGenerator.gaussRand }

let myMean = myGaussArr.reduce(0.0, combine: +)/Double(numGaussNumbers) // 0.0.. OK
let myVar = myGaussArr.map { pow(($0 - myMean), 2) }.reduce(0.0, combine: +)/Double(numGaussNumbers) // ~1, O

print("(\(myMean),\(myVar))") // ~(0,1), OK
```

OK.

Comment: Or I just saw that there is a random generator like this in gameplaykit.. :) but thanks for the answer

Comment: Was a bit quick there when reading your question, thought you want it translated but I see you ask for any kind of Gaussian generator ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a translation of Java's very efficient [`Random.nextGaussian()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) method into Swift:

```
private var nextNextGaussian: Double? = {
    srand48(Int(arc4random())) //initialize drand48 buffer at most once
    return nil
}()

func nextGaussian() -> Double {
    if let gaussian = nextNextGaussian {
        nextNextGaussian = nil
        return gaussian
    } else {
        var v1, v2, s: Double

        repeat {
            v1 = 2 * drand48() - 1
            v2 = 2 * drand48() - 1
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2
        } while s >= 1 || s == 0

        let multiplier = sqrt(-2 * log(s)/s)
        nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier
        return v1 * multiplier
    }
}
```

Now, to generate a gaussian random number given a mean and standard deviation, just do:

```
let myGaussian = nextGaussian() * myStandardDeviation + myMean
```